# What's the effect on other complexity classes if P=L?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, turing-machines, np-complete

Let's say theoretically we discover that the *P* complexity class (decision problems solvable by a polynomial time deterministic TM) is equal to the *L* complexity class (decision problems solvable by a logarithmic space deterministic TM), in other words **P=L** .

**How does it affect the class *EXP?*** (decision problems solvable by exponential time  deterministic TM)?

It's known that L⊆NL⊆P therefore we can conclude from L=P that L=NL=P, but does it affect the 'harder' classes as well, such as EXP?

Answer (score 2):

If L = P then PSPACE = EXPTIME.  By the [space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) we already know that PSPACE $\subsetneq$ EXPSPACE, so L = P gives us the previously unknown result EXPTIME $\subsetneq$ EXPSPACE.